# Using Jquery and Ajax to save the content of div element in a file

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have an php document,and inside the document PHP the table is loading  the records from the database , i'm adding jquery code in the end of the php document to save the 'table:eq(9)' content into an HTML  file

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
var bufferId = $("table:eq(9)").html();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saver.html",
    data: {
        id: bufferId
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: *"I want to save the PHP content after loading from the server in an HTML file."* This is confusing me. Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @FelixKling i have an php document,and inside the document PHP the table is loading  the records from the database , i'm adding jquery code in the end of the php document to save the 'table:eq(9)' content into a file

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then what you are trying to do is not possible. It does not seem to make a lot of sense either... why do you want to save the HTML in a different file if it is already contained in the current file? For starters, you cannot create local files with JavaScript. Sending the HTML back to the server seems to be unnecessary as well, because the server can just create the HTML.

Comment: @FelixKling yep you have the right for what you said , i have created the saver.html file in the directory , well the alert appears , but nothing is inserted , any idea ?

Comment: If `saver.html` is a simple HTML file, then sending a POST request to that file does not magically insert anything into it. You have to process the request by a server side script (e.g. with PHP) and modify the file with that script.

Comment: @FelixKling plz my bro ,can you be more specific ?

Comment: What did you not understand? You cannot modify a server side file with only JavaScript and Ajax. You need a server side script to process the Ajax request and modify the file. That's as specific as I can be.

Comment: @FelixKling and how can i do it ?

Comment: Access the data you send to the server, in your case via `$_POST` (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). And then open the file you want to edit and write to it, e.g. with `file_put_contents`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php.

Comment: @FelixKling yes totally understood , but the `file_put_contents` well get the entire page content , but what i want is just the content inside the ninth table in the page

Comment: I'm even more confused you know... do you want to **get** the the 9th table from `saver.html` or do you want to **save** the content of the 9th table from the current file in `saver.html`?

Comment: @FelixKling i want to save the content of the 9th table from the current file in `saver.html`

Comment: Then you might have to parse `saver.html` with http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and insert the data at the right position. But again, instead of sending the data with Ajax to the server, you could read the records from the database with PHP and directly insert them into `saver.html`. The easiest way of course would be if you just create the whole `saver.html` with PHP, I don't see a reason not to. I assume you are doing the same for the file where you have the JS in. It't the same. You have enough information to process now I think.